# Routing through bottlenecks

Tags: qgis, routing

I have two races in the same town that make use of the same stretches of roads/paths in places (sometimes in the same direction, sometimes in opposing directions).  Given that I know the pace of the fastest and slowest competitor in each race and the start time of each race, is there a QGIS tool that would allow me establish (and show) where the two groups of competitors would be sharing the same stretch of road/path?  That is where a conflict might arise.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have both roads as a line layer and divided them to sections for each intersection.
Once you have that go the attribute table and calculate the length of each line.
In the attribute table go to the calculator and make sure you are using the Decimal number [image].

In the project properties make sure you are measuring the length in the needed distance measurement [image]

If you know the running time for each group's just calculate the time to the  first intersection and find out when each group will be there and so on.
Have a good race!

Comment: Hi,if this was helpful please mark the question as finished